# How to make receiving node to stop automatically after one connection in D-ITG Traffic Receiver

Tags: mininet, network-traffic, iperf, traffic-simulation

I am performing a traffic generation between two hosts in mininet RYU using D-ITG. I used ITGRecv at receiving end and ITGSend at Sending host. But what I want is after completion of a flow between the nodes the receiver should shutdown that connection. What I mean is ITGRecv should accept only oneflow. Is it poasible?

I know that this could be possible with iperf with "-P 1" flag